# Mimic Streaming data after Reading from File in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

So i am reading data from a file. Something like

```
 data = spark.read.format('orc').load('myfilepath')
```

I want to now loop through every row of the above and create two arrays. One for customers who bought items and one for customers who sold items. I need this ordered by the price they bought the item for and the time they bought it at and if there were returns I want to update it / delete it from the array. And for every timepoint i want to see the inventory. For example lets say we have a list like table like this.

```
Item Bought Time | Item Price | Item Action        | Transaction Unique ID | Amount
     8.30             50          Bought               1                      2000
     8.31             51           Sold                2                      5000
     8.32             50       Bought Returned         1                      2000 
     8.33             52          Bought               3                      10000
     8.34             49          Bought               4                      3000
```

So i read the above as a dataframe. I would like to at every time point keep an array for bought items and sold items and order them by Price and Time so at any given point I would be able to get data sorted like the above of the bought and sold items.

Something like

**Bought Array**

```
    Time  Info
    8.30  [{50,2000}]
    8.31  [{50,2000}]
    8.32  []
    8.33  [{52,10000}]         
    8.34  [{49,3000}, {52,10000}]
```

**Sold Array**

```
    Time  Info
    8.30  []
    8.31  [{51,5000}]
    8.32  [{51,5000}]
    8.33  [{51,5000}]         
    8.34  [{51,5000}]
```

There are about 5 million rows per day so it needs to be performant as well. Could you let me know how best to do this?

Comment: You can use `collect_list` but that would work for one column at a time. Is that fine?

Comment: I will have a look at collect_list. Maybe it would be ok

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Window` from `pyspark.sql.window` and find the cumulative sum of the values then call `collect_list`

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy("Item Bought Time").orderBy("Item Bought Time")

df = df.withColumn("Cumsum_Price", F.sum("Item Price").over(w))
df_g = df.groupby("Item Bought Time").agg(F.collect_list("Cumsum_Price"))
```

Please specify exact business logic if you need more help on how to include it, which can be done using a `udf`

Comment: I think that may not work actually. For example for ID2, it needs to keep everything in ID1 and delete from the list if the item has been returned. So effectively adding some extra logic on the ID1 list and adding/deleting for ID2. Can this be achieved?

Comment: So do you need a cumulative sum? That is rather easy using a window function.